# unable to upload file using curl :Filename cannot be blank

Tags: php, file, post, curl

i'm using official [this](https://help.tune.com/hasoffers/create-file-upload-script/) script to upload the file. but response returns **ERROR:- Filename cannot be blank**

I have changed just parameters in script nothing else as they said. such as

```
$networkid = "RA";
$apikey = "XXXX"; 
$offerid = "2207";
$creativetype = "file";
$filename = "JetSmartShopping.zip";
```

**Response from script**

```
Array (
    [request] => Array ( 
        [Target] => OfferFile [Format] => json 
        [Service] => HasOffers 
        [Version] => 3 
        [Method] => create 
        [NetworkToken] => XXXX
        [NetworkId] => RA
        [data] => Array ( 
            [offer_id] => 2207 
            [type] => file 
            [display] => JetSmartShopping.zip 
        ) 
        [return_object] => 1 
        [JetSmartShopping_zip] => @JetSmartShopping.zip 
    ) 
    [response] => Array ( 
        [status] => -1 
        [httpStatus] => 200 
        [data] => 
        [errors] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [err_code] => 1 
                [err_msg] => Filename cannot be blank. 
                [attribute_name] => filename [publicMessage] => Could not create offer file. 
            ) 
        ) 
        [errorMessage] => Could not create offer file. 
    ) 
)
```

But if i use curl-command then it works

```
curl --verbose --globoff -X POST -F "xyz.zip=@xyz.zip" "http://api.hasoffers.com/v3/OfferFile.json?Method=create&NetworkToken=XXXX&NetworkId=RA&data[offer_id]=1899&data[type]=file&data[display]=xyz.zip&return_object=1"
```

I have checked some following requirements for this script

1. File to be uploaded should be in same path where script resides.
2. Tried some couple of other solutions from stackoverflow.
3. Given different name to file

But none of them worked for this script.

But the same file is getting upload using command and using their website.

Any one can figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP scripts says (under the  "Don't change anything below here" line :
$fields[$filename] = "@{$filename}";

But in your request I read this row:
[JetSmartShopping_zip] => @JetSmartShopping.zip

shouldn it be:
[JetSmartShopping.zip] => @JetSmartShopping.zip 
?

Have you edited the forbidden part of the script?

Comment: the array shown in question is response from server not request. I have changed just parameters from script nothing else. such as 
$networkid = "RA";
$apikey = "XXXX"; 
$offerid = "2207";
$creativetype = "file";
$filename = "JetSmartShopping.zip";